# how i can analyze which whats app status file is already saved in my my gallery in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist, whatsapp

i am trying to make a what's app status saver app in kotlin android studio where I am getting all status files from .statuses directory. I am succeeded to get all files, display in recycler view and saved. but one issue which I am facing one file can be saved multi-time on saved at every  click on saved button but i want saved picture can not save again until that is saved
so first I want to show this type of UI
[so first I want to show this type UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aKNG.jpg)

the after downloading want to display this type of UI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZHUw.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should achieve this by comparing between **.statuses** and your saved folder URI list. and when you save media then also save specific id(name etc.) in DB(Room or SQLite) and on the behalf of room list, you change your UI and also check in the save method if already exits then not save. hope you understand the flow

Comment: thanks this task is done by comparing